# openshift database connection

Tags: git, laravel, openshift

I created an openshift account and created an app with code that I had placed on github

I now get
PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I did the following

```
echo 'DB_HOST=>' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') . '<br>';
echo 'DB_PORT=>' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT') . '<br>';
echo 'DB_USER=>' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME') . '<br>';
echo 'DB_NAME=>' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME') . '<br>';
```

and received

```
DB_HOST=>127.7.249.2
DB_PORT=>3306
DB_USER=>adminRdUBaj3
DB_NAME=>audiocdf
```

All the information is correct. I do not know where to even start.

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying to connect via CLI `mysql -h$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -u$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -p $OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME` ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

is the syntax to connect to a mysql database

```
$DB_HOST = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
$DB_PORT = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT');
$DB_USER = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
$DB_PASS = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
$DB_NAME = getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME');

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME, $DB_PORT);
```

should do